# how can i use pip with pypy installed from launchpad?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pypy

I have ubuntu 11.10. I apt-get installed pypy from this launchpad repository: https://launchpad.net/~pypy the computer already has python on it, and python has its own pip. How can I install pip for pypy and how can I use it differently from that of python?

Answer (score 43):

Quoting (with minor changes) from here the [pypy website](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html):

> If you want to install 3rd party libraries, the most convenient way is
>   to install pip:
>
> ```
> $ curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
> $ ./pypy-2.1/bin/pypy get-pip.py
> $ ./pypy-2.1/bin/pip install pygments  # for example
> ```

In order to use it nicely, you might want to add an alias into e.g. `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias pypy_pip='./pypy-2.1/bin/pip'
```

Where the actual pip executable is located has to be taken from the output of `pypy get-pip.py`

Comment: CAUTION :in ubuntu it overrides  /usr/bin/pip in python-pip package!

Comment: I know this is old... but per @obayhan: installs and overwrites whichever `pip` in `/usr/local/bin/` which does take priority over `/usr/bin`. `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pypy-pip` sorts this out (and reinstall pip in local if you need to)

Answer (score 24):

To keep a separate installation, you might want to create a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for PyPy. Within the virtualenv, you can then just run `pip install whatever` and it will install it for PyPy. When you create a virtualenv, it automatically installs pip for you.

Otherwise, you will need to work out where PyPy will import from and install distribute and pip in one of those locations. [pip's installer](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) should do this automatically when run with PyPy. Be careful with this option - if it decides to install in your system Python directories, it could break other things.

Comment: Good idea, but -- A python or a pypy virtualenv? How do we create this ?

Comment: `virtualenv myenv -p /path/to/pypy`

Comment: `virtualenv myenv -p \`which pypy\``

Answer (score 21):

if you want to use pip with pypy:

```
pypy -m pip install [package]
```

pip is included with pypy so just target pip with the -m flag

Comment: $ pypy -m pip install visual

/usr/bin/pypy: No module named pip

Comment: @poizan42 download get-pip.py and run with the pypy executable then. otherwise, re-install pypy as it comes with pip.

Comment: @michaelg your solution still doesn't work on debian/ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `pip` installing from the `pypy` (at least when installing `pypy` via `apt-get`) is that it is installed into the system path:

```
$ whereis pip
pip: /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
```

So after such install, `pypy pip` is executed by default (/usr/local/bin/pip) instead of the `python pip` (/usr/bin/pip) which may break subsequent updates of the whole Ubuntu.

The problem with `virtualenv` is that you should remember where and what env you created.

Convenient alternative solution is `conda` (miniconda), which manages not only python deployments: http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html.
Comparison of `conda`, `pip` and `virtualenv`:
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html